# Adicionar javascript no worddpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Tenho uma aplicação que usa wordpress e preciso adicionar um javascript nela, vi vários vídeos e posts na internet e pelo que entendi é só fazer isso:

```
<?php
    wp_register_script("meuscript", "js/meuscript.js");

    function my_scripts_loader() {
        wp_enqueue_script("meuscript", "js/meuscript.js");
    }
    add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_scripts_loader");
?>
```

Porém não sei onde adicionar esse código fiquei meio confuso, vi algo sobre adicionar no tema ou algo assim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode colocar esse código no arquivo **wp-content/themes/SEU-TEMA/functions.php**

```
function load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts' );
```

Comment: Coloquei exatamente o código acima nesse caminho mas não funcinou

Comment: Coloca dessa forma https://pastebin.com/9zNCbXQ1

Answer (score 1):

Cara, dependendo de como está configurado seu tema é só colocar o caminho normalmente no header do tema que funciona.

```
<script src="caminhoDoSeuCodigo/code.js"></script>
```

Já fiz assim, não entendo muito de Wordpress mas funcionou no meu caso.

Comment: É a forma mais simples, também prefiro assim, só tem que ter cuidado se for trocar de tema.

Comment: Sim, eu achei mais fácil desse jeito.

Comment: Essa forma de fazer não é "errada"?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam se funcionou ta certo hehehe

Então como eu disse não entendo muito de wordpress acredito que tenha algum lugar para colocar que seja mais adequado para não dar pau quando trocar de tema.